# How to clear old Pop OS kernels

Tags: linux-kernel, pop-os

I am currently using Pop OS, and have been for maybe a year or so. A little while ago I ran into an issue with some package versions not matching up. I looked to see how to fix it and though I attempted to sort the issue it turned into such a headache, I figured I'd rather just to reset my OS. I didn't really have anything particularly precious so it was an easy option for me.

However while using a bootable drive to try and reinstall Pop OS (I didn't have a recovery partition), I ran into an issue where when I tried to wipe all the original files and kernel, it would throw an error saying that it couldn't complete the operation. At the time I was pretty frustrated and busy with other things in life, so I decided to just throw the new installation next to the old one and that seemed to work. It was quite a few months ago, so I am afraid I cannot recall the specific error or what exactly it is that I did to get where I am now, but suffice to say, despite the janky backdrop, things have been working pretty well.

Now, however, I'd like to do some "spring cleaning" if you will, and rectify the situation. I've backed up the files I care about and now my goal is to completely remove both installations and format both my ssd and my harddrive, and then once again install a fresh copy of Pop OS.

I am for all intents and purposes still pretty much a novice when it comes to Linux, and operating systems in general, so any advice that can be provided on the considerations I need to make moving forward would be greatly appreciated. And if anyone has any idea why I might've gotten that error when trying to clear the old kernel, advice for that would also be greatly appreciated.

I apologise if this question lacks the appropriate information. I admittedly am not sure what I can provide, but I will try my best to provide what I can.